# How to verify dimensions of image in Selenium Java Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to verify the first image on my page is a certain dimension. I have the code I'm using right now to GET the dimensions, but now, I need to verify that the image is 1024 pixels wide... How do I do this?

```
    Dimension elementDimensions=(Insert Element Here).get(0).getSize();
    elementDimensions.getHeight();
    elementDimensions.getWidth();
    Assert.assertTrue.........
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you already getting width and height from driver and known what would be the expected value. So you can use Assertions here..

Generally i will use like below

```
 driver.get("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");

      int width=driver.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getSize().getWidth();
      int hight=driver.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getSize().getHeight();

      System.out.println(width +">>>"+hight);

      //to verify width
      Assert.assertEquals(width, 200);
```

Thank You,
Murali