# Selenium webdriver: How to check an img element really have height attribute

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

in java Selenium web driver on chrome, I need to make sure that an image has a height attribute. The HTML code I have is this:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg">
```

and I'm trying to execute

```
 boolean s = driver.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("height") !=null;
```

but this always returns true **although there's no height attribute!** and if I try to execute

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("height");
```

I'll get 600 despite there is no height attribute in the HTML code. is there any other way I can check it?

Comment: Kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071128/how-to-verify-dimensions-of-image-in-selenium-java-webdriver) SO post if its help

Comment: OuterHTML of the element please?

Comment: @KuldeepKamune No it didn't work. it still returns the actual height and width of an image(even if the image doesn't have height and width attribute) what I need to know is if an image has height attribute or not.

Comment: @DebanjanB there's no outer HTML I need to check this on every image on a page.

Comment: @FaezehShayesteh: Hey, apologies, I didn't get your question at first time. I have posted method in answer using which generally I verify dimension. Kindly check if its help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```java
@Test
public void testHeightAttribute(){
    driver.get("https://webelement.click/en/welcome");
    WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[1]"));
    System.out.println(img.findElements(By.xpath(".[@height]")).size());
    System.out.println(img.findElements(By.xpath(".[@src]")).size());
}
```

I am not sure this is the most elegant way though :). The idea is that you're looking up elements using the element itself as a search context (looking up element within itself). If no attribute is present in DOM then the list would be empty (`size() == 0`). Otherwise it would be `1`.

Basically the common method would look like:

```java
public boolean hasAttributeInDom(WebElement element, String attr){
    return !element.findElements(By.xpath(".[@" + attr + "]")).isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. using xpath woked for me but I couldn't call findElement on ing (I have no idea why) I could get it work by addressing it directly like this: int imagesWidthNum = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@width]")).size()

Comment: When you say that there is a problem with calling `findElement` over `img` do you mean that if you copypaste my code you have issues? Or you try to adopt it to your case and get issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can check height parameter in `styles` section of Developer tools. Refer to attached  screen shot of sample image from Stack overflow. You can see `height` parameter at right hand side. Generally, dimension are mentioned here.

You will need to understand and look for particular image property in `Styles` section as its display `CSS` properties for entire page.

[image]